# How can the stress tensor be a contravariant second order tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I just read a proof showing that the stress tensor is a contravariant second order tensor and I cannot reconcile it with what I already knew of second order tensors.

A linear transformation $T\colon V\to V$ is a mixed second order tensor. A bilinear form $B \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a second order covariant tensor. Given that the stress tensor takes a vector and gives back a stress vector I would have expected it to be a mixed tensor like the linear transformation unless somehow its being thought of as a function $V\to V^*$ or $V^* \times V^*\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I would say that the stress tensor takes a plane (i.e. a 1-form) and gives a vector.

Comment: there is an isomorphism ${\rm hom}(V,V)\cong V\otimes V^*$

Comment: @janmarqz Ok that makes sense. I haven't seen an introduction to tensors explain stress tensors as that.

Comment: a rank two mixed tensor is bilinear map $V^*\times V\to\Bbb R$ and the set of all of these maps is the vector space $V\otimes V^*$.

Comment: @janmarqz I would give your answer the check mark if it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me reframe this in other words:

> If $V$ is finite dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ then there is an isomorphism $\hom(V,V)\to V\otimes V^*$.

Here, $\hom(V,V)$ is the vector space of linear transformations $V\to V$, and $V\otimes V^*$ a the space of rank two mixed tensors which correspond to the set of all bilinear maps $V^*\times V\to\Bbb F$.

Comment: In the case of the stress tensor being a contravariant second order tensor would this be $\hom(V^*, V) \to V \otimes V$

Comment: yes, these are the rank two contravariant tensor, but take into account their components are in this case, indexed above, as $T^{ij}$.

Comment: @user782220:  if you already grasp the isomorphism device, would you like to see other is the line of thoughts at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811697/tensor-products-acting-on-vectors/2812855#2812855 there, there're more details in terms of components