# Tensor Products Acting on Vectors

Tags: tensor-products

Is this always (if at all) true, and if so why?

$\nu\otimes\omega(v,w)=\nu(v)\omega(w)$

Where $\nu$ and $\omega$ are covectors, and $v$ and $w$ vectors.

Please tell me if the question or notation is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: it is true because is a definition and is important ´cuz it is a bilinear map

Comment: @janmarqz Thank you. Does this definition come from the universal property of the tensor product?

Comment: $\nu\otimes\omega$ lives in $V^*\otimes V^*$ and define a bilinear map $V\times V\to\Bbb F$

Comment: @janmarqz why not expand this some other way, like nu(w(v))*omega (sorry, I don't know how use LaTex in the comments).

Comment: mmmh.. another possibility is $\nu(v)\mu(w)-\mu(v)\nu(w)$ which is bilinear and alternating. This is used to define the exterior product $\nu\wedge\mu=\nu\otimes\mu-\mu\otimes\nu$.

Comment: @janmarqz Oh... so this is one of _many_ ways to expand this tensor product?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78614/discussion-between-benjamin-thoburn-and-janmarqz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give a kind of example:

Asertion: If $V$ is finite dimensional vector space over the field $F$, there is an isomorphism 
$$\hom(V,V)\to V\otimes V^*.$$

The key step is fixing basis.

Let $V={\rm gen}\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ and $V^*={\rm gen}\{\beta^1,...,\beta^n\}$. We can choose the basis requiring $\beta^k(b_l)=\delta^k{}_l$.

The space $\hom(V,V)$ consists of linear transformations $V\to V$ that can be thought as the matrices who spring in the linear combinations (supposing that $n=3$)
$$Tb_1=T^1{}_1b_1+T^2{}_1b_2+T^3{}_1b_3,$$
$$Tb_2=T^1{}_2b_1+T^2{}_2b_2+T^3{}_2b_3,$$
$$Tb_3=T^1{}_3b_1+T^2{}_3b_2+T^3{}_3b_3,$$
or briefly, à la Einstein-Penrose
$$Tb_k=T^s{}_kb_s\qquad\mbox{$s$- summation}.$$

Let $A=[T^i{}_j]$ be the matrix associated.

In another hand, the space $V\otimes V^*$ can be thought as the vector space span by the basic objects $b_i\otimes\beta^j$ which can be considered as bilinear maps $V^*\times V\to F$ working as
$$b_i\otimes\beta^j(f,v)=f(b_i)\beta^j(v).$$
So a generic element is characterized as a bi-indexed linear combination
$Q^{\mu}{}_{\nu}b_{\mu}\otimes\beta^{\nu}$.

With them now we can map
$$\Phi(T)=T^i{}_jb_i\otimes\beta^j.$$
That this map, $\Phi$, is a linear transformation and is injective is explained when is completed:

1) We have: $\Phi(aT+cS)=a\Phi(T)+c\Phi(S)$ for any pair of scalar $a,c$ and each pair of linear transformations $T,S$.

2) The kernel of $\Phi$ is trivial: We calculate 
$$\Phi(T)=\stackrel{\to}0,$$ 
and this is
iff 
$$T^i{}_jb_i\otimes\beta^j=\stackrel{\to}0$$
iff for any pair $(f,v)$ we have
$$T^i{}_jb_i\otimes\beta^j(f,v)=0.$$
But choosing basics $f=\beta^k$ and $v=b_l$ we get
$$T^i{}_jb_i\otimes\beta^j(\beta^k,b_l)=0.$$
This is 
$$T^i{}_j\beta^k(b_i)\beta^j(b_l)=0.$$
$$T^i{}_j\delta^k{}_i\delta^j{}_l=T^k{}_l=0$$
for all election $k,l$ so the linear map $T=\stackrel{\to}0$.

All this implies that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.